# libcurl curl_easy_setopt "Unknown error"

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use C++ cURL library for sending Json data via PUT method and my code looks something like this

```
CURL*    m_curlHandle;
CURLcode m_returnValue;

//function1 start
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
std::ostringstream oss;
struct curl_slist* slist = NULL;
slist = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
slist = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
slist = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

m_curlHandle = curl_easy_init();

if (!m_curlHandle)
    // throw exception

curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
//function1 end

//function2 start
std::string url = "some URL"; // my url
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
unsigned int timeout = 5;
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout);
std::string localIp = "some IP"; // my IP address
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, localIp.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
std::string json = "some json struct"; //my json struct
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callbackWriter); //static size_t callbackWriter(char* buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* userp);
m_returnValue = curl_easy_perform(m_curlHandle);
//function2 end
```

I call function1 then function2 and the problem is that for all `curl_easy_setopt` calls I get error code 1685083487 and error description "Unknown error". So what may cause to a such result and how to fix this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Judging just by the member variable names, this is a member function of a wrapper object. If said object is passed by value or otherwise copied implicitly or explicitly, and does not properly manage copy-semantics, and your disruptor closes `m_curlHandle`, any by-value copy will be holding a `m_curlHandle` that is invalid. Attempts to use it will fail. My advice: declare the class copy-ctor as deleted, recompile and fix whatever breaks.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're right these are member functions of a wrapper class, but it's a singleton, so there is only one object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS instead, my func was something like this

```
void poolStr(const std::vector<unsigned char> &data, const std::string &url)
{
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
mCurl = curl_easy_init();
if(mCurl) 
{

        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, data.size());
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, &data[0]);
        mChunk = curl_slist_append(mChunk, "Content-Type: application/binary");
        mChunk = curl_slist_append(mChunk, "Expect:");
        curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, mChunk);

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(mCurl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            LOGERROR << "curl_easy_perform() failed: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << "\n Attepmt number: " << attempt;
        }
        else
        {
            LOGINFO << "Data being sent.";
        }
    }
}
}
```

and calling like poolStr(data, mHost);

Comment: but `curl_easy_setopt(mCurl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());` also returns 1685083487 code, before `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.